# Finding All Ring Homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_m$ to $\Bbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, ring-homomorphism

I was working through Abstract Algebra : A Geometric Approach (by Theodore Shifrin) and I came across this exercise that I am struggling with.

($ℤ_m$ means integers mod m)

Find All Ring Homomorphisms:

$ϕ:ℤ_m \longrightarrow  ℤ_n$ (your answer will depend on the relationship between m and n).

Here is what I have so far:

If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$:

then the only homomorphism is trivial: $ϕ(x) = 0$

If $ m < n$, then:

$ϕ(0) = 0\;$ and 
$\;ϕ(x) = k$ , such that $k^2 ≡ k\pmod n$ and $2k ≡ 0\pmod n$.

I'm not sure how much of this is correct, or what to do in the case m>n.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In any of these rings, once you know $f(1)$, you know the entire homomorphism $f$.  (That's because $k=\sum_{i=1}^k 1$, so $f(k) = \sum_{i=1}^k f(1)$.)  So what are the possibilities for $f(1)$?

Comment: wouldn't the possible values for $f(1)$ be $0,...,n-1$ ?
I am confused as to how this will help find a generalization

Comment: Not all of those values are possible because $m=0 \Rightarrow mf(1)=0$.

Comment: I don't know what $x$ means in your formula. You should think about two cases: $m<n$ and $m>n$, and divisibility will be crucial. Remember that the definition I take in the text requires a ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R\to S$ to map $1_R$ to $1_S$.